# TileLayout with dynamic rows and columns for paging

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, layout, flex4

I'm implementing an image gallery which presents assets as equally sized boxes that are forming a grid. I thought that I could easily achieve that by using the `spark.layouts.TileLayout` but unfortunately I have some additional requirements that I'm unable to implement with it.

The general principal should to be to present as many *boxes* as possible within given space. The entire layout of the application is `liquid` and depends on the user's screen resolution.

I've started from a basic `DataGroup` with a `TileLayout`:

```
<s:DataGroup id="dgpImages" width="100%" height="100%" top="12" dataProvider="{ list }" 
    minHeight="0" minWidth="0" clipAndEnableScrolling="true" itemRenderer="LibraryImageRenderer">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout orientation="rows" clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
            requestedColumnCount="-1" requestedRowCount="-1"
            verticalGap="12" horizontalGap="12" useVirtualLayout="true" />
    </s:layout>
</s:DataGroup>
```

I don't know the *RequestedColumnCount* or *RequestedRowCount* in advance as they depend on the available space, so the above code layouts all elements from `left-to-right` and then from `top-to-bottom` - which is as close as you can get from what I really want to achieve.

**The problem**

This list of *boxes* should be cable of rendering *fake* paging. In reality it means that if the last visible row does not entirely fit the available space it should be moved to the next page.

To give you an example let's imagine that we have a list of 10 images. Each one is 10x10 px but my screen resolution only allows me to fit a grid 35x35 px. This means that one *page* is only capable of presenting 9 images in form of a 3x3 grid (as 5 px is not enough to present a full image). The 10th image should be then *transferred* to the second page.

**The question**

This is obviously not happening automatically with the code that I've pasted above as the `TileLayout` allows for displaying partially visible rows (in a form of a vertically scrolled list). **I was wondering how I could achieve the behavior described above.**

If the above description does not sound logical please let me know so that I can adapt it (or include more details).

Any help on this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: There's no actual question here... What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, the question part was indeed missing :) - check my update

Comment: Personally, I think you'd be better off creating a custom component for this kind of functionality. You can calculate the size and by knowing the explicit height/width of what you want to display, you can know how many rows/columns are needed.  After that, it's only a matter of changing the data depending on which 'page' you want to select (since you won't be using a scrollbar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a custom layout for this kind of functionality.  Good news is I found a tutorial doing almost the exact thing you want to do for ya here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/spark_layouts.html

So implement that first.  in the updateDisplayList() method, look for this line :

```
if (x + elementWidth > containerWidth)
```

when checking for bumping it to the next line, youll check the total height versus the current row height and stop adding elements if it exceeds the boundries. (just `break` out of the for loop)

Then, all you have to do is page the `dataProvider` for the group based on the current page.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice on the custom layout, I've implemented it with virtualization using this article: http://flexponential.com/2010/03/06/learn-how-to-create-a-simple-virtual-layout-in-flex-4/ - greatly improves the performance. Cheers!